# How to apply conditions for CSS Modules?

Tags: css, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm using CSS modules for my react project. I just want to apply Conditional classNames for one of component in the project. How can I do it?

```
import classes from "./Header.module.css"
```

**I want to apply in here**

```
<ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
```

Comment: use 'classnames' library. Super useful!

Answer (score 3):

What you would have to do:-

`<ul className={click ? classes['nav-menu-active'] : classes['nav-menu']}>`

Why the above ?

Because `classes` is an object.

Although for clean code, use `clsx` package and use `.active` instead of `nav-menu-active` like so:-

`<ul className={clsx(classes['nav-menu'],click && classes.active)}>`

[clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) allows easy grouping of class names and removes falsy values from the DOM and you will not see dangling `undefined`, `null` or `false` in your class names.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You are accessing the `class` names incorrectly.

### Solution

Use it like object.

`<ul className={ classes.nav-menu + ' ' + ( click ? classes.active : '' ) }>`